# How to create a mini-map in XNA 3?

Tags: xna, maps

[simple map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IERst.jpg)

The map i would like to create is like this one, but simpler , what i want to have is a geographical map indicate high /low and a point that show where am i and  points indicate enemies

Thank you

Comment: The implementation depends on a number of factors that you didn't specify. Does the map need to rotate like the one in the picture? And what shape do you want it to be?

Comment: To be more clear here's the possible solutions depending on your requirements (1) No rotation + Rectangle shape = SpriteBatch with special sourceRectangle and destinationRectangle parameters. (2) Rotation + Rectangle Shape = SpriteBatch with vertex shader like [this](http://www.david-gouveia.com/scrolling-textures-with-zoom-and-rotation/) example. (3) Rotation + Any other shape = SpriteBatch with stencil buffer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want that minimap for 3D game

1. If your environment is created from heightmap then use heightmap as minimap
2. Or just move camera up, to face down the ground, change projection to orthographic, and render it as depth map.

If you want to know just how to draw minimap, you can use SetData on Texture2D, to create texture and then pass it to spriteBatch.Draw